# Vue vee-validate server side error not being set at all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-6, vee-validate

I've got the following form:

```
<ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
                    <form name="side-category" class="mb-4 md:flex md:flex-wrap md:justify-between" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(onSubmit)">
                        <div class="md:w-full px-3">
                            <ValidationProvider name="Side" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors, failedRules }">
                                <label for="name" class="tracking-wide mb-2 uppercase font-bold text-xs text-grey-darkest">Side Category Name</label>
                                <input
                                        type="text"
                                        name="name"
                                        id="name"
                                        v-model.lazy="form.name"
                                        data-vv-as="beware asshole!!!"
                                        class="w-full border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 bg-gray-200 text-blue-900 md:mr-2"
                                >
<!--                                <span v-if="failedRules.required">Yo! Save something!!!</span>-->
                                <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                            </ValidationProvider>
                            <button id="submit-btn" class="bg-green-300 font-semibold hover:font-bold hover:bg-green-500 text-green-800 uppercase text-sm mx-auto p-2 rounded float-right"></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ValidationObserver>
```

My `data` method is the following:

```
data() {
            return {
                id: null,
                mode: 'new',
                form: {
                    name: ''
                }
            }
        },
```

and my submit method is:

```
onSubmit() {
                axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/sidecategories', this.form)
                    .then(response => {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log(response)

                            this.$router.push('/sidecategories/list')
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {

                        if (!err.response.data.success) {
                            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                            console.log(err.response.data.data)
                            // { name: ['test error']}
                            this.$refs.form.setErrors(err.response.data.data)
                        }
                    })
            }
```

The problem that I have is that `this.$refs.form.setErrors` is not setting any error at all. If I print `err.response.data.data` (response from Laravel backend) I get the following:

```
{{"name":["The name has already been taken."]}}
```

which according to vee-validate's documentation is the format expected by `setErrors`.

I'm using vee-validate 3.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from the docs:

> The keys of the errors object **must match the provider's vid or name props** and the values must be an array of strings containing the corresponding field errors.

Currently you have the vid set to "Side" which is not right.  I would try changing the name/vid props on your `ValidationProvider` like this:

```
<ValidationProvider name="name" vid="name" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors, failedRules }">
```

Comment: Indeed, that was the issue. I appreciate your help. Will try to read the docs next time instead of jumping to the example right away